Creating App bundles using jetpack compose multiplatform for android and desktop
I havnt found any documentation on how to create app bundles for windows/android using kotlin compose multiplatform
i could run the apps using an emulator,
see the build process but couldnt find any installer/bundle
i have seen the publish article on jetbrains but it doesnt specify how to compile and distirbute.

https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/tutorials/Native_distributions_and_local_execution/README.md
